# Existence and Uniqueness of complex ODE's

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm wondering if there is a theorem for the existence and uniqueness of complex ODE's. If there is, would someone mind explaining the general breadth of the theorem and/or directions to an online source detailing this theorem? That would be great.

Comment: Do you mean that functions are complex-valued, or that their domain is in the complex plane? If it's the latter, then the subject is worth a book: such as [Ordinary Differential Equations in the Complex Domain](http://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations_in_the_C.html?id=I1OR4t8UZCgC) by Hille, an inexpensive book published by Dover.

Comment: The latter, function of complex variable. I will certainly look at, but would you happen to have any information of a theorem of the type I mentioned.